# celery task failed when I it has been run using supervisord

Tags: python, celery, supervisord

I'm trying to run a simple python script which has a few argument like this :

```
python2.7 script.py 'a_file_path' some_file_name 'another_file_path'
```

I've used subprocess.call inside a celery task to run above line :

```
BASE_DIR = getattr(settings, "BASE_DIR")
OUTPUT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "output"))
PYTHON_2_BIN = getattr(settings, "PYTHON_2_BIN")
MAKESPRITES_SCRIPT = getattr(settings, "MAKESPRITES_SCRIPT")


@shared_task
def process_video(*args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('video_id') is None:
        return "No Video id provided"
    vid = kwargs.get('video_id')
    video = UploadedVideo.objects.filter(id=vid).first()
    if not isinstance(video, UploadedVideo):
        return "Video id is not exists"
    video_output_dir = os.path.join(OUTPUT_PATH, str(video.id))
    filesystem.mkdir_p(video_output_dir)
    command = [
        PYTHON_2_BIN,
        MAKESPRITES_SCRIPT,
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploaded_files', video.file_name),
        video.file_name,
        video_output_dir
    ]
    with open(os.devnull, 'w') as FNULL:
        subprocess.call(command, stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    video.state = 2
    video.save()
    return "thumbnails has been generated"
```

If I run celery manually from command line everythings work just fine and there is no problem but when I use supervisord (or [init.d](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#generic-init-scripts)) the scripts won't run properly and will terminate with non-zero exist status 1 .

my supervisor configuration :

```
[program:celery]
command=/home/develop/video-hosting/env/bin/python3.4 /home/develop/video-hosting/env/bin/celery worker -A VideoHost --loglevel=DEBUG

directory=/home/develop/video-hosting
user=develop
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/home/develop/logs/worker.log
stderr_logfile=/home/develop/logs/worker.err
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=3    
stopwaitsecs = 600    
killasgroup=true    
priority=1000
```

EDIT 1 :
There is absolutely no problem with the celery task itself , it will run in both cases (manually and using supervisord)

EDIT 2 :
[this](https://github.com/vlanard/videoscripts/blob/master/sprites/makesprites.py) is the script which I'm trying to run .

EDIT 3 : 
even the external script itself will run in both cases but wont finish when the celery has been run with supervisord.

Comment: Quick guess is it can't find `python2.7` due to the wrong current working directory or `PATH` not being correct.  You could "call" `which python2.7` to verify it can find it.

Comment: You're redirecting all your useful output to null.  Why not print it while debugging this and check the celery log?

Comment: @rrauenza nope , I checked python2.7 path is correct
and output had not any useful information .

Comment: You said your script runs in both cases, but exits early with supervisord.  You need to add some output to narrow down where your script is exiting.